# Ownbackup Validation Rules

Tags: api, salesforce, multipartform-data, apex

I would like to see if anyone else already had this problem. I'm really struggling to find out an solution for that, so that's why I've decided to call for help.

So, i have this Ownbackup API endpoint:

[Ownbackup API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utsM7.png)

Here's the link for the API documentation: [https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2571574/api%20document-1.html#tag/Enhanced-Sandbox-Seeding/paths/~1api~1v1~1sbs~1templates~1{template_id}~1seed/post](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2571574/api%20document-1.html#tag/Enhanced-Sandbox-Seeding/paths/%7E1api%7E1v1%7E1sbs%7E1templates%7E1%7Btemplate_id%7D%7E1seed/post)

But for me it wasn't too helpful.

The point in here is that my organization has hundreds of validations rules. **And I would like to know if there is any parameter that this API understands in order to disable ALL validation rules**, without the need of passing the name of each one of the file names in the request body.

Keep in mind that the format for this request is multipart/form-data.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

So, I've reached out for Owbackup support and they told me that i can actually use "disable_validation_rules" set to true, so this way the All validation rules get disabled and the triggers not, also it does not require me to specify which validations rules should be disabled.

I'm letting this answer in here, in order someone else comes across this problem!
Cheers!

[image]